# Replacement for 'https://live.azure.com/'?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to set up the customer and partner portals for CRM 2011 and am having a really hard time. I followed the documentation for the portals (the ones from pinpoint, default portals that come with the Contoso domain) but when I get to the part asking me to register my application I just don't know what to do...

In the documentation it says go to https://live.azure.com/ and register the application but this site does not exist anymore or at least I can't seem to get to it (tried to google it but I can't come accross anytihng that will allow m to register an application). Is there a new site where you register the application? Someone please help me because this is really annoying me and its pretty stupid that Microsoft does not update its documentation at all.

Thanks for any help! :)

Details about my setup: We (net admin and I) set up CRM 2011 in a test environment in the office and have Exchange and CRM 2011 sitting on two environments. I can communicate through Exchange and emails from CRM but I can't figure out how to allow users access to this Customer portal and Partner portal. This is all using the Contoso domain and sample data.

Comment: Anyone??? I can't seem to get any user access to the portal...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and [answer to this thread](http://www.datazx.cn/Fv7p5a/q7-HR/975ys8a/2q7xs6/i9rc8rgd-9rsi-fjxm-sfds-x6bbjj8ijidm23rsdfd.html) helps me. Moreover, check next article - [Getting Your Client ID for Web Authentication](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144070), for some extra info.

You can go to the Windows Live application management site via [this link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144070).